# why grafana display the value at incorrect time slot?

Tags: grafana, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics, grafana-api

I used grafana to display data from cloudwatch. I found grafana shows value incorrectly, for example, from this graph, the test_value is 1.000 at time 2021-02-28 07:29:00, [image]

however, from this graph, u can see the test_value is still 1.000 at time 2021-02-28 10:29:00, while the bar graph shows there should be no test_value at this time slot; [image]

it is very confused to see this? maybe the grafana setting is wrong? any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have sparse metric, so Grafana is showing the closest previous value. I would switch `Hower tooltip` `Mode` to `Single` instead of `All series` to avoid confusion.

You can also use [CloudWatch Metric Math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) with `FILL()` function to fill the missing values of a metric with the specified filler value when the metric values are sparse.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a bug? Why grafana should show the last value in a different time?